# php create new .txt file with specific name ending

Tags: php, html, forms, unique, fopen

I have a site which has an HTML form that forwards some information to php code. Then once the php document has gotten the code it creates a new document `newDocu.txt` and then it writes two values to it. Only problem is that when this has been done one time, it will just append to that same document as it has already been created.

I was then wondering if there is a way to change the naming of the new document, so lets say it would look at the current documents in the folder and then lets say there are no documents, then it would be `newDocu1.txt` or if there were three documents, then the new txt file would be called `newDocu4.txt`. To make sure it doesn't just write the new info to a current document.

Any help is very much appreciated.

### Here is my current php file

```
<?php

    $field_fname = $_POST['fnameInput'];
    $field_email = $_POST['emailInput'];

    $filename = "../public_html/NO/newDocu.txt";

    $f_data= '
    First Name : '.$field_fname.'
    Email : '.$field_email.'
    --------------------------------------------------
    ';

    echo 'Thank you!';

    $file = fopen($filename, "a");
    fwrite($file,$f_data);
    fclose($file);

    echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=index.html">';

?>
```

Comment: why not just use some form of uniqueness right away, rather than checking if it already exists? You'd save yourself a lot of coding. There are many ways of using unique methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code just after your `$filename` variable:

```
$mainname= $filename;
$version = 1;
while(file_exists($filename))
{
    $filename = str_replace('.txt', $version . '.txt', $mainname);
    $version++;
}
```

Comment: Why it shouldn't work?

Comment: @AsmirZahirovic thank you very much for the input, it actually does work. The only small thing is that with your version the new documents created, are like document one = newDocu1 and then document two is newDocu12 and the next newDocu123. Where I was thinking of something where it would just be newDocu1, newDocu2 and then newDocu3. But it works no problem, it will just have a very big amount of numbers if 100 documents were to be created.

Comment: I meant it it won't increment.

Comment: Fixed it, it should increment now, my bad, I haven't tested code. Btw, this is not the best solution, but it can help you until you figure out new idea how to do it. As this post is marked as duplicate, you can find better solution than mine in link mentioned abowe.

Comment: @AsmirZahirovic Thank you very much, everything works now just like I wanted it to.